# Can I point a domain to two web hosting services by adding A records in my DNS Records?

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, web-hosting, dns-hosting, a-record

Can I point a domain to two web hosting services by adding A records in my DNS Records?

What happens if I do that?

Comment: You'd basically be doing https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_DNS. Some users will wind up on one host, some on the other. They might switch mid-session, so if you've got sessions or a database you'd have to have them be synced up. It gets quite complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you do that?

- Yes you can.

What happens?

- ~50% of all visitors that tries to visit your website will either visit SERVER-A or SERVER-B. It is called "Round Robin DNS".

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_DNS